# How to check if the text is given in Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart

How can I check if the text from TextFormField is empty?
I have this sample code:

```
                TextFormField(
                  controller: firstNameController,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(136, 136, 136, 1)),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide()),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                    hintText: sharedPreferences.getString("firstName")
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String value){
                    final trimValue = value.trim();
                    if(value != trimValue){
                      setState(() {
                        if(trimValue != ""){
                          firstNameController.text = trimValue;
                        }else{
                          firstNameController.text = sharedPreferences.getString("firstName");
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

I try with `if(trimValue != "")` statement but after run this widget, my console throw me:

```
I/flutter (20342): UsageError: Cannot perform update with the provided values.
I/flutter (20342): Details:
I/flutter (20342):   Could not use specified `lastName`.  Cannot set "" (empty string) for a required attribute.
```

I want it to check if a string is given, if is given he get text from the controller, if it is not he sending text from shardPreferences,

have anybody any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing does not make sense because what you are trying to do is check it against itself `firstNameController.text/trimValue` the *firstNameController.text* *is* the *value* from the onChanged() property. There is no need to have an onChanged() property if you are going to use `TextEditingController`.

What I suggest is to actually use `addListener()` method to check for changes.

```
final firstNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    firstNameController.addListener(_checkIfFieldIsEmpty);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _checkIfFieldIsEmpty listener.
    firstNameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _checkIfFieldIsEmpty() {
   if (firstNameController.text.trim().isEmpty) {
        firstNameController.text = sharedPreferences.getString("firstName"); 
    }
   }
```

Comment: I don't need a validator here

Comment: But that is exactly what you are doing with the onChange property, are you not? This will check if there is text in the text field, if it is empty, then it will give a message, else it won't.

Comment: I dont want it, i want to set sharedPreferences in onChanged if field is empty